# Code not working on Phone, but working on Emulator, Why?

Tags: android, android-emulator

This code works perfectly fine on an Emulator (Geneymotion), but doesn't work in phone, or tablet:

```
     Document doc = new Document();
     try {

                 String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
 + "/invoices";

                 File dir = new File(path);
                 if(!dir.exists())
                     dir.mkdirs();

                 Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

                 File delete = new File(dir, "invoice.pdf");
                 if (delete.exists())
                     delete.delete();

                 File file = new File(dir, "invoice.pdf");

 FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

             PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

             //open the document
             doc.open();
             Paragraph name = new Paragraph("NAME");
             doc.add(name);
     } catch (DocumentException de) {
                 Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
             }
     finally
     {
        doc.close();
     }
```

I've added the required permissions.

My question is, why would a piece of code work in an emulator, but not on the actual device? Isn't an emulator suppose to emulate a device? So shouldn't the outcome be the same?

The above code runs when I click a button, in the emulator when I click that button, it creates the file in the designated directory, but when I test it in a phone, when I press the button, nothing happens, no file is created, nor is any folder created.

What is the problem? Can anyone give me some direction please.

Comment: install any pdf reader in you phone and try with same code ... genymotion default it will supoort the pdf

Comment: I don't think any code within the try statement runs, because hence, the folder is not created either. The code is either catching a DocumentException, or an IOException, what I want to know is why it is working in Geneymotion, but not in phone.